# What is the binomial expansion of this sequence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$S_n$ = $(1 + \frac{1}{n+1})^{n+3}$

I just want to know the first 4 terms  ,

The first term is obviously 1 and the second term is $( \frac{n}{n+1})$

the third term is what ? i am really lost

Answer (score 2):

$$(1 + \frac{1}{n+1})^{n+3} = 
\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n+3}{n+3\choose k} 1^{n+3-k} (\frac{1}{n+1})^r = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n+3}\frac{(n+3)!}{(n+3-k)! \cdot k!} (n+1)^{-k}$$

As you can see, a general term in a binomial expansion of $(1+X)^N$ is $$ T_{k+1} = \binom {N} {k} X^{k}$$

So, you want the first 4 terms of $\lbrace 1 + (n+1)^{-1} \rbrace^{n+3}$?
Here you go:

---

$$T_1 = T_{0 +1} = {n+3\choose 0}\cdot (n+1)^{-0} = 1\times 1 = 1 $$

---

$$
T_2 = T_{1+1}= {n+3\choose 1}\cdot (n+1)^{-1} \\
= \frac{(n+3)!}{(n+3-1)! \cdot 1!} \cdot \frac{1}{n+1} \\
= \frac{(n+3)!}{(n+2)!} \cdot \frac{1}{n+1} \\
= \frac{n+3}{n+1}
$$

---

$$
T_3 = T_{2+1} = {n+3\choose 2}\cdot (n+1)^{-2} \\
= \frac{(n+3)!}{(n+3-2)! \cdot 2!} \cdot \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} \\
= \frac{(n+3)!}{(n+1)! \cdot 2} \cdot \frac{1}{(n +1)^2} \\
=  \frac{(n+2)(n+3)}{2(n+1)^2} 
$$

---

$$
T_4 = T_{3+1} = {n+3\choose 3}\cdot (n+1)^{-3} \\
= \frac{(n+3)!}{(n+3-3)! \cdot 3!} \cdot \frac{1}{(n+1)^3}\\
= \frac{(n+3)\cdot (n+2)\cdot (n+1)\cdot n!}{n!\cdot (3\times 2 \times 1)\cdot (n+1)^3} \\
= \frac{(n+3)(n+2)}{6(n+1)^2}
$$

---

Hope this helps and please read up on the [Binomial Theorem](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/binomial-theorem.html)

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd term is: (n+3)(n+2)/(2(n+1)^2).

Comment: mm the second term is not right , i guess it sould be (n+3)/(n+1) right ?

Comment: @user3196567: true

Answer (score 0):

Either I do not understand properly the question or there is something wrong in the formulation of the problem.

If the terms are defined according to
$$S_n=(1 + \frac{1}{n+1})^{n+3}$$
then $S_0=8$, $S_1=\frac{81}{16}$,  $S_2=\frac{1024}{243}$, $S_3=\frac{15625}{4096}$, $S_4=\frac{279936}{78125}$,$S_5=\frac{5764801}{1679616}$ and $S_{\infty}=e$.

I do not see what the binomial expansion is supposed to do in the problem.